# Как оптимизировать запрос с EXCEPT на NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть запрос, который делает следующее: "Вывести список ФИО преподавателей, которые никогда не выставляли ни одной оценки ниже 3"

```
SELECT Chelovek.FIO FROM Chelovek 
JOIN -- даёт из номеров паспортов фамилии
(SELECT P.NumerPassporta FROM Prepodavatel AS P
 JOIN --даёт из названий курсов номера паспортов

(SELECT  b.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka b -- все курсы
EXCEPT  -- минус -- таблица, где хотя бы 1 тройка
SELECT a.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka a WHERE a.PromezhutochnyeOcenka1<=3 OR a.PromezhutochnyeOcenka2<=3 OR a.PromezhutochnyeOcenka3<=3 OR 
 a.ItogovayaOcenka<=3) Raznost  

 ON P.RaspisanieKursNazvanie=Raznost.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie) Pass
 ON Pass.NumerPassporta=Chelovek.NumerPassporta;
```

Таблица Chelovek определена следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE Chelovek               
(
NumerPassporta NVARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL CHECK (NumerPassporta!=''), -- так как NULL и пустая строка это разные вещи
FIO NVARCHAR(200) UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(FIO !='')
);
```

Таблица Prepodavatel:

```
CREATE TABLE Prepodavatel               
(
    NumerPassporta NVARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL CHECK (NumerPassporta!=''), -- так как NULL и пустая строка это разные вещи
    FOREIGN KEY (NumerPassporta)  REFERENCES Chelovek(NumerPassporta),
    Kvalifikaciya NVARCHAR(200)  UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- Квалификация
    PredydushcheeMestoRaboty NVARCHAR(200) NULL, --Предыдущее место работы
    Zarplata MONEY NOT NULL CHECK (Zarplata >0 ),
    RaspisanieKursNazvanie NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,--FK 
    FOREIGN KEY (RaspisanieKursNazvanie)  REFERENCES RaspisanieZanyatij(KursNazvanie),
    ZHurnalOcenokKursNazvanie NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL CHECK (ZHurnalOcenokKursNazvanie!=''), --ЖурналОценокКурсНазвание
    FOREIGN KEY (ZHurnalOcenokKursNazvanie)  REFERENCES ZHurnal_Ocenok(KursNazvanie),

);
```

И таблица Ocenka:

```
CREATE TABLE Ocenka
(
    Id INT IDENTITY ,--PRIMARY KEY,
    PromezhutochnyeOcenka1 INT NOT NULL CHECK (PromezhutochnyeOcenka1>0),--ПромежуточныеОценки
    PromezhutochnyeOcenka2 INT NOT NULL CHECK (PromezhutochnyeOcenka2>0),--ПромежуточныеОценки
    PromezhutochnyeOcenka3 INT NOT NULL CHECK (PromezhutochnyeOcenka3>0),--ПромежуточныеОценки
    ItogovayaOcenka int NOT NULL CHECK (ItogovayaOcenka>0),
    ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL CHECK (ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie!=''),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN_KursNazvanie FOREIGN KEY (ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie)  REFERENCES ZHurnal_Ocenok(KursNazvanie),
    ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta NVARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL CHECK (ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta!=''),
    --FOREIGN KEY (ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta) REFERENCES Obuchayushchijsya(NumerPassporta)
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_KEY_Id PRIMARY KEY(Id)
    
);
```

Я хочу произвести оптимизацию в запросе следующим образом: заменить EXCEPT на NOT EXISTS, то есть заменить внутренний подзапрос

```
(SELECT  b.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka b -- все курсы
    EXCEPT  -- минус -- таблица, где хотя бы 1 тройка
    SELECT a.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka a WHERE a.PromezhutochnyeOcenka1<=3 OR a.PromezhutochnyeOcenka2<=3 OR a.PromezhutochnyeOcenka3<=3 OR 
     a.ItogovayaOcenka<=3) Raznost
```

на такой же по смыслу, но вместо EXCEPT использовать NOT EXISTS.

Но мои попытки построить такой "заменяющий" подзапрос - тщетны:

```
SELECT  b.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka b
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT a.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka a WHERE a.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie=b.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie and 
        ( b.PromezhutochnyeOcenka1<=3 OR b.PromezhutochnyeOcenka2<=3 OR b.PromezhutochnyeOcenka3<=3 OR  b.ItogovayaOcenka<=3)
  )
```

Можете помочь построить правильную замену EXCEPT на NOT EXISTS или есть оптимизация получше?

Comment: ни одной ниже 3 фильтруется просто с помощью `select .... having min(x) >= 3`

Comment: @teran, а что в x помесить? Все четыре пункта сравнения?

Comment: Вам ничего не поможет, в Ocenka нет подходящих индексов, там небось полный перебор таблицы. если так, то not exists только хуже сделает. Плюс к этому связь таблиц под длинному varchar полю плохая идея, оно сравнивается заметно дольше каких нибудь int. А вообще надо начинать с просмотра плана выполнения запроса (explain) что бы понять как оно сейчас работает и в какую сторону идти

Comment: А по поводу x думаю в having надо так и написать 4 условия, раз у вас 4 поля, т.е. по каждому отдельно получаете минимум и убеждаетесь что это конкретное поле никогда меньше тройки не было.

Answer (score 0):

В запросе

```
SELECT  b.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka b
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT a.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie FROM Ocenka a WHERE a.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie=b.ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie and 
        ( b.PromezhutochnyeOcenka1<=3 OR b.PromezhutochnyeOcenka2<=3 OR b.PromezhutochnyeOcenka3<=3 OR  b.ItogovayaOcenka<=3)
  )
```

в условиях подзапроса - замените `b.Prome...` на `a.Prome...`.
По логике вы накладываете условие на внутреннюю таблицу подзапроса, то есть а, а условия оценок ставите на b, то есть внешнюю таблицу.